# Deep autoencoder always worse than shallow

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, autoencoder

I am trying to model gene pexression data. I have run many experiments and they all come to same conclusion - best performing autoencoder is the one that has only 1 layer as encoder, 1 layers as decoder. Theoretically it does not make any sense. Here is how I define shallow network:

```
#Leaky-Parametric-RelU
#Encoder
encoded = Dense(num_genes,activation = 'linear')(input_data)
encoded = PReLU()(encoded)

#Bottleneck layer
encoded = Dense(128,activation = 'linear')(encoded)
encoded = PReLU()(encoded)

#Decoder
decoded = Dense(num_genes,activation = 'linear')(encoded)
decoded = PReLU()(decoded)

decoded = Dense(num_genes,activation = 'linear')(decoded)
```

And here is how I define deeper network:

```
#Leaky-Parametric-RelU
#Encoder
encoded = Dense(num_genes,activation = 'linear')(input_data)
encoded = PReLU()(encoded)
encoded = Dense(int(num_genes/2),activation = 'linear')(encoded)
encoded = PReLU()(encoded)


#Bottleneck layer
encoded = Dense(128,activation = 'linear')(encoded)
encoded = PReLU()(encoded)

#Decoder
decoded = Dense(int(num_genes/2),activation = 'linear')(encoded)
decoded = PReLU()(decoded)
decoded = Dense(num_genes,activation = 'linear')(decoded)
decoded = PReLU()(decoded)

decoded = Dense(num_genes,activation = 'linear')(decoded)
```

Then I compile model with:

```
autoencoder = Model(input_data, decoded)
#Model = Sequential()
autoencoder.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'adam') 
autoencoder.summary()

history = autoencoder.fit(x_train,x_train, 
                           epochs =500, verbose = 2, 
                           callbacks = [MyCustomCallback()])
```

I have tried different activation functions. I run in for 100 or 500 epochs and save the best MAE value. This values is always lower for a shallow network. Deeper network give weird results like:

[image: Performance of deep autoencoder]

Data is normalized, taken from GTEx portal. Here is how data distribution looks like:

[image: Data distribution:]

How can this be, any help is appreciated, I am really stuck with this.

Answer (score 3):

It can be normal if your data is not very large. There is this concept of the Deep Double Descent (here is [Open Ai blogpost](https://openai.com/blog/deep-double-descent/)). Basically until certain point the simpler model would perform better than a more complex one, and model complexity pays off when you have substantially more data or can afford bigger training times (it's explained much better in a blog I referenced and also [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-double-descent-when-more-data-and-bigger-models-are-a-bad-thing-3a3f108d5538).

I understand there isn't much practical use in this answer, so if you want to improve your model performance, I would concentrate on tuning the shallow network.

Comment: Num genes is 17020, and 4000 training samples plus 700 validation. Perhaps it is indeed not enough for the deeper network to work efficient. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try `kernel_initializer='he_uniform'` for every `Dense` that has ReLU activations. (PReLU is similar to ReLU, so this initializer might still be better than others).

You must also take care with the size of `num_genes`. If `num_genes / 2 < 128`, you might be creating more bottlenecks, especially in the second model where the number of units in the layers seem to be inverted.

A suggestion would be `num_genes` -> `128 + (num_genes - 128) / 2` -> `128 (bottleneck)`. Then going up do the exact reverse order.

Comment: Num genes is 17020. Total samples I have is ~5000. I will try initializer suggestion.

Comment: Make an initial prediction to see whether your values are exploding before training.

Comment: After adding the kernel_initializer to the last (output) layer my loss is nan :-(

Epoch 1/500
 - 110s - loss: nan
Current epoch Validation MAE:  nan Best MAE:  0
Current epoch Validation MSE:  nan
New best MAE:  nan

Comment: You were absolutely right about the decoder being inverted... However I have just put that in while giving another try to it. Normally they were in the right order.

Comment: @AlexanderAksjonov 5000 samples for 17020 dimensions means your problem is underconstrained, and that is a big problem, you need at least 17020 samples.